# disable selection of text except for one class

Tags: css

I have a website on which I have made all text non selectable except for input and textareas using the following line of CSS:

```
*:not(input, textarea) { -webkit-touch-callout:none; -moz-user-select:none; -khtml-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none; }
```

I'd like to add a class so I can add certain texts to also be selectable. I thought adding ".selectable" to the selector would be enough, but somehow this doesn't work. Should it?

Comment: I don't see the class "selectable" used in your code? How are you trying to make it work?

Comment: `not()` doesn't have any logical operators. I'd set all to no select, and then use one more rule to enable those you need.

Comment: :not(.nonselectable) { user-select : text} should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate rule for `.selectable` class to make it select text.

```css
*:not(input, textarea) {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.selectable{
  -webkit-touch-callout: default;
  user-select: text;
}
```

```html
<div>In this block, only <span class="selectable">this</span> is selectable. </div>
```